# Search as you type functionality in Javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to Implement search as you type feature and I'm not sure how to get substring after I type '@' in textarea.

Here is the fiddle what have I done https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/zp3hx8ag/13/

```
$('#text').on('input', function(e) {

    if(e.originalEvent.data == '@') {
      $('.list').show();
      let cursorPosition = $(this).prop('selectionStart')

    $(this).on('input', function(e) {

      if(e.originalEvent.data == ' ') {
        $('.list').hide();
      } else {
        let value = $(this).val();
        let textForSearch = value.substr(cursorPosition, value.indexOf(' '))
        console.log(textForSearch)

        $(".list li").each(function() {
          if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(textForSearch) != -1) {
            $(this).show();
          }
          else {
            $(this).hide();  
          }
        });
      }

    });
  }

});
```

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>

<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

```
.list {
  display: none;
}
```

Trying to figure out how to get text in this line:
value.substr(cursorPosition, value.indexOf(' ')) - trying to get substring from cursorPosition until first blank space after cursor position. I can type @ anywhere in the text not just at the end.

Comment: Have you looked into using regular expressions?

Comment: Regular expressions are your friend here. Something like `(/w* )` might be what you need (capture group added for clarity to highlight trailing space), but be warned - that will only match words (no digits or whitespace). See this link regexr.com/4guf9

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes on your own code and now its working.
this is how it works.
We trace user input char by char,
if it was '@' we set cursorPosition to index of cursor.
else if was 'space', then we check :
if text we have so far, is only spaces, just pass.
else  textForSearch is substr of cursorPosition to current input index without leading and ending spaces (trim()).
then we compare with li's text.

Js:

```
let cursorPosition = -1;
$('#text').on('input', function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.data == '@') {
        $('.list li').show();
        cursorPosition = $(this).prop('selectionStart');
    }
    else if(e.originalEvent.data == ' ') {
        if (cursorPosition != -1 ){
            let value = $(this).val();
            let textForSearch = value.substr(cursorPosition,  
            $(this).prop('selectionStart')).trim().toLowerCase();
            if(! textForSearch){
                $('.list li').hide();
                return;
            }
            $(".list li").each(function(i, li){
                if($(li).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(textForSearch)) != -1) 
                {
                    $('.list').show();
                    $(li).show();
                }else {
                    $(li).hide();  
                }
            });
        }

        else{ 
              $('.list li').hide();
        }
     } 
  });
```

CSS:

```
.list li{
    display:none ;
}
```

Comment: Actually I can't do it like that. First I already have cursorPosition so no need for text.indexOf('@') and second this won't work because I can have multiple '@' in a text. So I) need text from cusrosPosition until first blank space after cursorPosition

Answer (score -1):

**I have modified the JS code**

Try this javascript code instead of what you are using.
working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/raghulramkish/9mq0pbhk/

```
    var textForSearch="";
    var textareaValue="";
      $('ul.list li').click(function(e) 
        { 
        var val=$(this).text();
         textarea = document.getElementById('text').value;
          textarea = textarea + val;


     document.getElementById('text').value=
       textarea.replace("@"+textForSearch,"");
        });
```

On click on the list the above section will add the option to the text area (e.g:instead of "@On" it will replace to One)

```
    $('#text').on('input', function(e) {

        if(e.originalEvent.data == '@') {
        $('.list').show();
        let cursorPosition = $(this).prop('selectionStart')

        $(this).on('input', function(e) {

          if(e.originalEvent.data == ' ') {
            $('.list').hide();
          } 
          else {
            let value = $(this).val();
             textForSearch = value.substr(cursorPosition, value.indexOf('@'))


            $(".list li").each(function() {
              if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(textForSearch) != -1) {

                $(this).show();
              }
              else {
                $(this).hide();  
              }
                });
          }




        });
      }

    });
```

Instead of using "  textForSearch = value.substr(cursorPosition, value.indexOf(' '))" use  "textForSearch = value.substr(cursorPosition, value.indexOf('@'))".